# Issue in composer update/install

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php, lamp

I try to install the composer but it not works and give the below mentioned issue after following different different steps. Please help if you know how can I resolve it

> [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
>   No valid bower.json was found in any branch or tag of
>   https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git, could not load a package
>   from it.

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4"
composer install
```

give the key, after some time it says permission issue unable to create vendor folder, give the permission to the folder and run

```
composer update
```

it gives the above mentioned error, then i run

```
composer clear-cache
composer install
```

give the key, but not it gives above mentioned issue.

Below mentioned is my composer file.

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "twilio/sdk": "^5.11",
        "endroid/qrcode": "^2.3",
        "2amigos/yii2-flysystem-component": "^1.0",
        "cedricziel/flysystem-gcs": "^1.1",
        "league/flysystem-cached-adapter": "^1.0",
        "mpdf/mpdf":"*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-slider": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-checkbox-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/bootstrap-popover-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-popover-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable": "*",
        "kartik-v/dependent-dropdown": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-field-range": "*",
        "kartik-v/bootstrap-checkbox-x": "*",
        "kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-markdown": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-file-input-widget" : "*",
        "razorpay/razorpay": "1.*",
        "kop/yii2-conditional-validator": "dev-master",
        "nodge/yii2-eauth": "~2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide content of  your `composer.json` file. Please also specify what composer version do you use

Comment: Try switch to asset-packagist: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49965495/5812455

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your **composer.json** , however as i can see you already tried

`composer clear-cache` in your project.

so try this :

go to **/root/.composer** directory, and create file **config.json** and put these command inside it.

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "github-protocols": ["https","http"],
        "github-oauth": {
            "github.com": "YourGithubOauth"
        }
    }
}
```

then clear cache again. and I wish its work.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav, please look into the composer file and let me know if is there any thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your composer.json file

```
"repositories": [
    {
       "type": "composer",
       "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
]
```

If Still doesnt work. Try removing fxp/composer-asset-plugin :

```
composer remove fxp/composer-asset-plugin
or
composer global remove fxp/composer-asset-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating composer-asset-plugin to the latest version:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error. The simple trick that was to remove vendor folder partially created before and run `composer install` again.